# How to fix: "Always-on screen" OFF, causes irregular location updates on android wear

Tags: android, location, wear-os

I am getting location updates in a service via FusedLocationProviderClient. Problem is: When "Always-on screen" is disabled on the watch, the location updates become very irregular.

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Try to use use Google Play services version 11.6.0 or higher, it includes bug fixes for the [`FusedLocationProviderClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was actually not the location provider but android restricting the resources of the encapsulating service since it wasn't configured as a ForegroundService. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services):

> If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on using or creating background services unless the app itself is in the foreground. If an app needs to create a foreground service, the app should call startForegroundService().